# Get time in seconds from string and add to current time?

Tags: ruby, time

timestr = '15h 37m 5s'

I want to get the hours minutes and seconds from the above string and add it to current time.

```
  def next_run
    timestr = '15h 37m 5s'
    timearr = timestr.split(' ').map { |t| t.to_i }
    case timearr.count
    when 3
      next_ = (timearr[0] * 3600) + (timearr[1] * 60) + timearr[2]
    when 2
      next_ = (timearr[1] * 60) + timearr[2]
    when 1
      next_ = timearr[2]
    else
      raise 'Unknown length for timestr'
    end
    time_to_run_in_secs =  next_
  end
```

Now I get the total seconds. I want to make it into hours minutes and seconds, then add it to current time to get next run time. Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method can be used to compute the the numbers of seconds from the string.

```
def seconds(str)
  3600 * str[/\d+h/].to_i + 60 * str[/\d+m/].to_i + str[/\d+s/].to_i
end
```

Note `nil.to_i #=>0`. A slight variant would be to write `3600 * (str[/\d+h/] || 0) +...`.

Then

```
Time.now + seconds(str)
```

Examples of possible values of `str` are as follows: `”3h 26m 41s”`, `”3h 26m”`, `”3h 41s”`, `”41s 3h”`, `”3h”`,`”41s”` and `””`.

One could instead write the operative line of the method as follows.

```
%w| s m h |.each_with_index.sum { |s,i| 60**i * str[/\d+#{s}/].to_i }
```

Though DRYer, I find that less readable.

Comment: This covered all of cases. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[`DateTime#+`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-2B) accepts `Rational` instance as *days to be added*. All you need as you have seconds would be to convert it to a number of days and plain add to the current timestamp:

```
DateTime.now.tap do |dt|
  break [dt, dt + Rational(100, 3600 * 24) ]
end
#⇒ [
#    [0] #<DateTime: 2018-05-27T11:13:00+02:00 ((2458266j,33180s,662475814n),+7200s,2299161j)>,
#    [1] #<DateTime: 2018-05-27T11:14:40+02:00 ((2458266j,33280s,662475814n),+7200s,2299161j)>
# ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly instead of `split`ing the string, you can use `Time#parse` [method](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-parse). Make sure you have required the library as well.

```
require 'time'
=> true
Time.parse('15h 37m 5s')
=> 2018-05-27 15:37:05 +0300
```

This returns a new object of class [Time](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html) and it has some really useful methods for you - `#sec, #min, #hour`.

```
time = Time.parse('15h 37m 5s')
time.sec       #=> 5
time.min       #=> 37
time.hour      #=> 15
```

Adding adding one `Time` object to another is pretty straightforward since you can do it only by `seconds`. A simple solution for the current problem would be:

```
def next_run
  time = Time.parse('15h 37m 5s')
  seconds_to_add = time.hour * 3600 + time.min * 60 + time.sec
  Time.now + seconds_to_add
end
```

Hopefully this will answer your question! :)

Answer (score 1):

you can convert your string into seconds from this method

```
def seconds(str)
  (3600 * str[/\d+(h|H)/].to_i) + (60 * str[/\d+(m|M)/].to_i) + (str[/\d+(s|S)/].to_i)
end
```

and then convert current time to seconds using method

```
next_run_time = Time.now.to_i + seconds(<Your Time String>)
```

now get next run time using

```
Time.at(next_run_time)
```

get desired format of time by using strftime method, in your case

```
Time.at(next_run_time).strftime("%Hh %Mm %Ss")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to parse the duration of time, and just want to define it in your code, use `ActiveSupport::Duration` for readability . (add [the gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport) to your Gemfile, and read [the guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html) on how to use it)

Then you can use it like this:

```
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext/integer'    

DURATION = 15.hours + 37.minutes + 5.seconds
# use DURATION.seconds or DURATION.to_i to get the seconds

def next_run
  Time.now + DURATION
end
```

See the [API documentation of ActiveSupport::Duration](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html)

If you need to define the next run by a user input, it's a good practice to use ISO 8601 to define a duration of time: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations

ISO 8601 durations are parseable:

```
ActiveSupport::Duration.parse('PT15H37M5S') # => 15 hours, 37 minutes, and 5 seconds (duration)
```